# Save images in 300 dpi using phpimageworkshop

Tags: php, image, image-processing, printing

Hello I am working on a screen to print application, with a front end javascript customizer that will send then send xml data via ajax to my server.
I am using [phpimageworkshop](http://phpimageworkshop.com/)

to generate the final customized images, everything is working well except for the final output file which is being outputted in 72 DPI even though the initially uploaded image is of 300 DPI. For my purpose I need the final output in print ready 300 DPI, Here is the simple code for generation.

```
<?php
use PHPImageWorkshop\ImageWorkshop; // Use the namespace of ImageWorkshop
require_once('PHPImageWorkshop/ImageWorkshop.php'); // Be sure of the path to the class
$pinguLayer = ImageWorkshop::initFromPath(__DIR__.'/images/cards-01.jpg');
echo $pinguLayer->getWidth();
echo $pinguLayer->getHeight();
//$pinguLayer->resizeInPixel(400, null, true);

$wwfLogoLayer = ImageWorkshop::initFromPath(__DIR__.'/images/wwf.png');
$tuxLayer = ImageWorkshop::initFromPath(__DIR__.'/images/tux.png');

/*$wwfLogoLayer->resizeInPixel(64, 64, true);
$tuxLayer->resizeInPixel(64, 64, true);
*/
$pinguLayer->addLayerOnTop($wwfLogoLayer, 20, 10, 'LB');
$pinguLayer->addLayerOnTop($tuxLayer, 20, 10, 'RT');

$dirPath = __DIR__."/exports/";
$filename = "pingu_edited.jpg";
$createFolders = true;
$backgroundColor = null; // transparent, only for PNG (otherwise it will be white if set null)
$imageQuality = 100; // useless for GIF, usefull for PNG and JPEG (0 to 100%)

$pinguLayer->save($dirPath, $filename, $createFolders, $backgroundColor, $imageQuality);
?>
```

Is there anyway for specifying the output in 300 DPI?